Ranking formula in Google Spreadsheet
I'm new to Google Spreadsheet and I have a problem with the ranking formula. Please help me to solve this problem



EXAM SCORE
RANK NUMBERS




-2500
1


-400
2


-400
2


-1
3


0
4


1
5


2
6


2
6



I've tried using the formula =rank(A2 , $A$2:A , 1) but it doesn't work.
So here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164h2OpzOVWVf-8_zTRA4ws2p7tvxXSlAZSqkEZqf6ig/edit?gid=0#gid=0

The =RANK function returns the normal way of ranking the winners in a race, where a tie for 2nd means there is no 3rd.  You need something different, so you're going to have to write it yourself.

Try the following formula-
=XMATCH(A2,UNIQUE(SORT($A$2:$A$9)))

Dynamic spill formula-
=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(x,UNIQUE(SORT(TOCOL(A2:A,1))))))



Can this formula be used if the range is like $A$2:$A ?

Your second formula (dynamic formula) is what I need. Thank you Mr. Harun24
